# Interfacing Arduino Uno with OV7670 (with FIFO)?

Tags: arduino-uno

I need help with interfacing ov7670 to Aduino Uno. I know there is a lot of literature available but the problem is that all this literature is for ov7670 without FIFO. I have Ov7670 with FIFO and its a 22-pin image sensor. I haven't been able to relate the available tutorials to my module. Any help in this regard is appreciated. (I need Wire Configuration as well as Code to get images).
Kind Regards,

Comment: so your module is different that standard  oc7670? (from first look at the first datasheet from google) the chip itself has its own FIFO does your module have additional IC with FIFO ... how about link to datasheet of your module or at least circuit diagram ...Also as usually for arduino platform what MCU you have and what pins available (Arduino is not processor !!!)....